# How to make an empty div or container glow with pure CSS?

Tags: css, glow, box-shadow

I want an empty container to glow so I use this code:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 1px lightcyan;
```

The problem with this is that only the borders glow and there is a big hole in the center which is not the effect I want. I know I can move the position of the shadow so is not overlapped by the container itself but I don't want that because it would be out of place.

Is there any other alternative to achieve this effect with pure CSS?

Something like this, but without the background:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the desired effect would be like? A picture would be helpful, because your description doesn't really describe what you want, only what you don't want.

Comment: Something like this but without the background https://clojurefun.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/2012-10-04-moon-glow.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-shadow` can do it, just crank up the blur and the spread (the 3rd and 4th parameters).

For a circle, add `border-radius: 50%;` and give a small `width` and `height`.

```css
div {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: lime; /* for the 1px in the center */
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 70px lime;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thats the solution I had come up with at the end.